# GROUP BY error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

When I delete Group By clause it works. The main problem is that the query gets repeated rows, so I added Group By to clear the results.

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    O.ItemCode, O.ItemName
FROM OITM O 
    JOIN OITW OI ON O.ItemCode = OI.ItemCode 
WHERE O.ItemName LIKE '%a%' 
GROUP BY O.ItemCode 
ORDER BY PATINDEX ('a%', O.ItemName) DESC, 
    LEN(O.ItemName) ASC
```

The error I get is just

```
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]The cursor was not declared.
```

But deleating the line `GROUP BY O.ItemCode` fix it

EDIT:
Adding all the rows works in last query. Thanks

Now this is the complete query

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    O.ItemCode, O.CodeBars, O.ItemName, CONVERT(INT, OI.OnHand) AS Stock
FROM OITM O 
    JOIN OITW OI ON O.ItemCode = OI.ItemCode WHERE O.ItemName LIKE '%a%' 
GROUP BY O.ItemCode, O.CodeBars, O.ItemName, Stock
ORDER BY PATINDEX ('a%', O.ItemName) DESC, 
    LEN(O.ItemName) ASC, 
    PATINDEX ('%a%', O.ItemName) DESC, 
    PATINDEX ('%a', O.ItemName) DESC
```

Error

```
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Stock'.
```

Comment: You should use all the columns you are selecting in `group by` clause.

Comment: you aren't aggregating anything.... so can you provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: If you only want values from OITM why are you joining to OITW at all?

Comment: You don't need a group by if you have no aggregation.  if you have duplicate records based on the select use distinct, or as RP indicated use all the columns in the select in your group by.

Comment: @RP- ok it work but I short down the query. I have a select as `CONVERT(INT, OI.OnHand) AS Stock` and now I get error `[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Stock'`

Comment: That error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: I think you would need to `Sum(Convert(int, OI.onhand)) as stock` as each item could have stock in multiple OITW's (whatever that is)  or use the formula in the group by, not the alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO: 
GROUP BY  is generally for use with aggregate functions (Sum, Count, Max, Min, Avg)

DISTINCT is to eliminate duplicates when selecting non key values

I think you need to sum your stock as OI could have multiple onHand values for each item.

```
 SELECT TOP 5 O.ItemCode
            , O.CodeBars
            , O.ItemName, 
            , sum(CONVERT(INT, OI.OnHand)) AS Stock
FROM OITM O 
INNER JOIN OITW OI 
   ON O.ItemCode = OI.ItemCode 
WHERE O.ItemName LIKE '%a%' --Very slow can't use index
GROUP BY O.ItemCode
       , O.CodeBars
       , O.ItemName
ORDER BY PATINDEX ('a%', O.ItemName) DESC
       , LEN(O.ItemName) ASC
       , PATINDEX ('%a%', O.ItemName) DESC
       , PATINDEX ('%a', O.ItemName) DESC
```

Or you need to add your convert to a group by but then you have multiple itemcode, codebars and itemname's possible which I think you were trying to avoid and since your order by doesn't take into account the onhand values, I think a sum is what you're after (or a min/max/avg)....

The group by doesn't have knowledge of the alias at run time. so you have to enter the formula.  Only the order by would have knowledge of the alias.

```
 SELECT TOP 5 O.ItemCode
            , O.CodeBars
            , O.ItemName, 
            , CONVERT(INT, OI.OnHand) AS Stock
FROM OITM O 
INNER JOIN OITW OI 
   ON O.ItemCode = OI.ItemCode 
WHERE O.ItemName LIKE '%a%'  --very slow can't use index
GROUP BY O.ItemCode
       , O.CodeBars
       , O.ItemName
       , CONVERT(INT, OI.OnHand) --alias not available must use formula
ORDER BY PATINDEX ('a%', O.ItemName) DESC
       , LEN(O.ItemName) ASC
       , PATINDEX ('%a%', O.ItemName) DESC
       , PATINDEX ('%a', O.ItemName) DESC
```

Comment: `GROUP BY CONVERT(INT, OI.OnHand)` works! Thanks for your time

Comment: Impressive.  I couldn't make sense of the question ... and I do know all my letters and numbers  +1

Comment: Well the question changed 2-3 times.  At first it was missing a group by, then they added a selected value from a table not initially listed then they tried to group by the alias.  The edit history alone should scare you away. (I almost was)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    O.ItemCode, O.ItemName
FROM OITM O 
    JOIN OITW OI ON O.ItemCode = OI.ItemCode 
WHERE O.ItemName LIKE '%a%' 
GROUP BY O.ItemCode,O.ItemName
ORDER BY PATINDEX ('a%', O.ItemName) DESC, 
    LEN(O.ItemName) ASC
```